# Change List to Dict Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, arraylist

Imagine that you have:

```
value = ["Name:","Mike", "Hobby:", "bakset", "voly"]
```

What is the simplest way to produce the following dictionary?

```
output : {"Name:" : ["Mike"], "Hobby:" : ["bakset", "voly"]}
```

with python

Value with ":" would be the key for dictionary

Comment: Does it mean any value with `:` will be the key?

Comment: Where did this list come from?

Comment: the list is a value that I got from scraping, I want to convert it like the following dictionary above.

Comment: Scraping gives you Python data structures? How?

Answer (score 1):

Dict comprehension:

```
>>> {v: (a := []) for v in value if v[-1] == ':' or a.append(v)}
{'Name:': ['Mike'], 'Hobby:': ['bakset', 'voly']}
```

Though I suspect you're not sharing the original data but already processed data, and that there's a better way to directly build from the original data. Possibly with an existing parser for the format.